# Effecient way to split range of DateTimes

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timestamp, date-range

I have two DateTime's, X and Y. Where X always occurred before Y. They might be milliseconds to years apart from each other. How can I in C# efficiently split them up on date end (00:00)?

```
E.g (24h clock)

X: 2010-01-01 14:00
Y: 2010-01-02 11:00
Result
2010-01-01 14:00 - 2010-01-02 00:00
2010-01-02 00:00 - 2010-01-02 11:00

-

X: 2010-01-01 05:00
Y: 2010-01-03 18:00
Result
2010-01-01 05:00 - 2010-01-02 00:00
2010-01-02 00:00 - 2010-01-03 00:00
2010-01-03 00:00 - 2010-01-03 18:00

-

X: 2010-01-01 05:00
Y: 2010-01-01 06:00
Result
2010-01-01 05:00 - 2010-01-01 06:00

-

X: 2010-01-01 02:00
Y: 2010-01-04 22:00
Result
2010-01-01 02:00 - 2010-01-02 00:00
2010-01-02 00:00 - 2010-01-03 00:00
2010-01-03 00:00 - 2010-01-04 00:00
2010-01-04 00:00 - 2010-01-04 22:00
```

Comment: Take the start date, add one day, truncate the time.  If that is before the end date then you have one partition.  Continue to do that until the date is after the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that will do the partitioning that you want.  Note there is no checking to make sure the initial `start` is before `end`.

```
public IEnumerable<(DateTime Start, DateTime End)> DaySplit(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var partition = start.AddDays(1).Date;
    while(partition < end)
    {
        yield return (start, partition);
        start = partition;
        partition = start.AddDays(1);
    }

    yield return (start, end);
}
```

Note that will create the ranges lazily so you'll have to iterate it to get the values either in a `foreach` loop or by calling `ToList` or `ToArray` on it.  Additionally it uses value tuples from C# 7.  You can instead use `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>` or a custom type instead.